# Variable inner foreach - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need return listarCliente model to my view, to select a value from another table inside my Foreach, but havent sucess and var_dump return null

Model

```
function listarCliente($id){
    $this->db->from('ga845_clientes');
    $this->db->join('ga845_cupons', 'ga845_cupons.clientes_id = ga845_clientes.id');
    $this->db->where('ga845_cupons.id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();
}
```

Controller

```
public function index(){
    $cliente_cp = $this->cupons_model->listarCliente($id);

    $data['cliente_cp']    = $cliente_cp;
    $data['registros']      = $this->cupons_model->listar();

    $this->template->set('titulo_pagina', 'Administração | Cupons');
    $this->template->load('adm/template', 'adm/cupons', $data);
}
```

PHP

```
foreach($registros as $registro):

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><span style='display:none;'>".$registro->valido_ate."</span>".converteData($registro->valido_ate)."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$registro->tipo_cupom."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$cliente_cp[0]->nome."</td>"; //need return here.
    echo "<td>".($registro->tipo_desconto == 'fixo' ? 'R$ '.ConverteReal($registro->valor) : $registro->porcentagem.'%')."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$registro->codigo."</td>";
    echo "<td>".($registro->enviado == 1 ? 'Sim' : 'Não')."</td>";
    echo "<td>".($registro->status == 1 ? 'Sim' : 'Não')."</td>";
    echo "<td class=\"toolbar\">
            <div class=\"btn-group\" >
                <a class=\"btn btn-flat\" href=\"".base_url()."adm/cupons/alterar/".$registro->id."\">
                    <span class=\"awe-wrench\"></span>
                </a>
                <button class=\"btn btn-flat\" onclick=\"if(confirm('Deseja realmente excluir o registro?')) window.location.href='".base_url()."adm/cupons/excluir/".$registro->id."';\">
                    <span class=\"awe-remove\"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
          </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    endforeach;
```

Comment: where is `$id` defined?

Comment: It's because your `$id` is not defined.

Comment: @KayoBruno where I can define in my view? I need do it inside a foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `$id` argument to the controller

```
public function index($id){ //<--here
    $cliente_cp = $this->cupons_model->listarCliente($id);

    $data['cliente_cp']    = $cliente_cp;
    $data['registros']      = $this->cupons_model->listar();

    $this->template->set('titulo_pagina', 'Administração | Cupons');
    $this->template->load('adm/template', 'adm/cupons', $data);
}
```

Now trying to access the controlle like this

```
localhost/ci_path/index.php/your_controller/3
```

Here `3` is `registros` id.